# Framework name aliases on Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, header-files

I'm using Xcode to build an external source code (not originally written for OS X). On has an include

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
```

But to compile on OS X, with the headers in `OpenCL.framework`, it would have to be

```
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
```

Is there a way to specify that `CL/` should be an alias to `OpenCL/`, without modifying the source code?